# Why is my child's leige my spouse's?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am playing as a queen, and I have 4 children. My first two have my husband as their liege, and my youngest two have me as their liege. Why are they not all mine? My oldest two have grown up, and now I cannot arrange marriages for them. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to get those 2 children back under your control so you can arrange a marriage for them short of something extreme like declaring war on your husband after divorcing him. However, you can still propose a marriage, so I would advise finding a high quality potential spouse, giving him/her a small title so they will accept the marriage and getting your children married to someone decent that way.

I think the reason that your husband is the leige for some of them has to do with when you/he received land, or a previous marriage, or a couple other possible factors. It's hard to guess without more info